# When do Injection dependency Integration Event, controller not called c#

Tags: c#, microservices, event-bus

I am trying to make communication between microservices using eventbus, when I use dependency injection my controller can no longer be called.

I have my `Controller`

```
  public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
        private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;
        private readonly ICustomerIntegrationEventService _customerIntegrationEventService; 

        public CustomersController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository, IIdentityService identityService, ICustomerIntegrationEventService customerIntegrationEventService)
        {
            _customerRepository = customerRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerRepository));
            _identityService = identityService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(identityService));
            _customerIntegrationEventService = customerIntegrationEventService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerIntegrationEventService));
        }

        }
```

In this `Controller`, I have a method named `Add`. It basically adds a client. When client is added, I would like to notify other microservice and send the data to a service bus. So far I'm using Integration Event. But in the moment that the dependency injection is done in the controller. the front can no longer hit the controller, returning an error `500`.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Customer value)
        {
            var idAdded = await _customerRepository.Add(value).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!idAdded.HasValue)
                return BadRequest();
            var integrationEvent = new CustomerIntegrationEvent(idAdded.Value, value);
            await _customerIntegrationEventService.AddAndSaveEventAsync(integrationEvent);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = idAdded.Value }, null);
        }
```

Soon below is how this class building _customerIntegrationEventService

> CustomerIntegrationEventService

```
  public class CustomerIntegrationEventService : ICustomerIntegrationEventService
    {

        private readonly Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService> _integrationEventLogServiceFactory;
        private readonly IEventBus _eventBus;
        private readonly ApplicationDataContext _osDataContext;
        private readonly IntegrationEventLogContext _eventLogContext;
        private readonly IIntegrationEventLogService _eventLogService;

        public CustomerIntegrationEventService(
            IEventBus eventBus,
            ApplicationDataContext hrDataContext,
            IntegrationEventLogContext eventLogContext,
            Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService> integrationEventLogServiceFactory)
        {
            _osDataContext = hrDataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hrDataContext));
            _eventLogContext = eventLogContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventLogContext));
            _integrationEventLogServiceFactory = integrationEventLogServiceFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(integrationEventLogServiceFactory));
            _eventBus = eventBus ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventBus));
            _eventLogService = _integrationEventLogServiceFactory(hrDataContext.Database.GetDbConnection());
        }

        public async Task PublishEventsThroughEventBusAsync()
        {
            var pendindLogEvents = await _eventLogService.RetrieveEventLogsPendingToPublishAsync();
            foreach (var logEvt in pendindLogEvents)
            {
                try
                {
                    await _eventLogService.MarkEventAsInProgressAsync(logEvt.EventId);
                    _eventBus.Publish(logEvt.IntegrationEvent);
                    await _eventLogService.MarkEventAsPublishedAsync(logEvt.EventId);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    await _eventLogService.MarkEventAsFailedAsync(logEvt.EventId);
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task AddAndSaveEventAsync(IntegrationEvent evt)
        {
            await _eventLogService.SaveEventAsync(evt, _osDataContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction());
        }
    }
```

all of these codes were taken from the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/subscribe-events

I made the dependency injection in the startup, but anyway the error persists

```
     public void AddIntegrationServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddTransient<Func<DbConnection, IIntegrationEventLogService>>(
              sp => (DbConnection c) => new IntegrationEventLogService(c));

            services.AddTransient<ICustomerIntegrationEventService, CustomerIntegrationEventService>();

        }
```

How could I at least see the error behind things, or how I come up with that solution. This code is based on microsoft eShopOnContainers

Comment: The 500 error is what the client sees - just an indication that something failed with no explanation - and that's okay. But in order to figure it out we need to know what the actual exception is, which is something that would come from debugging your code or logging.

Comment: I have used the eshopcontainer libraries and normally this happens when one of your dependency is not getting initiated. The easiest way to isolate the dependency is to remove them one by one and see which one is breaking.

Comment: Typically I'd expect to see an Add method decorated with `[HttpPost]` ahead of the method.  When you call it, are you GET'ing or POST'ing?

Comment: How to check for a failed library? Is it possible?